# AWS Step Functions - Transform input using ResultSelector

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a step function with multiple parallel steps. each having lambdas.
output of one parallel function is supplied to next parallel function.

i would like to tranform output of 1st function

{"x":11111, "y":"New"} to

{"x":11111, "y":"Existing"} this will then be the input of second function

i tried achieve it like below

"ResultSelector": {
"x.$": "$.x",
"y.$": "Existing"
}
i get the below error when i try to save it
The value for the field 'y.$' must be a valid JSONPath or a valid intrinsic function call

my question here is it possible to hardcode value here.
any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ResultSelector you used `y.$` that means that you want to use JSONPath or intrinsic function, if you want to use hardcode value, then use `y`, so your ResultSelector should be like this:

```
"ResultSelector": { "x.$": "$.x", "y": "Existing" }
```